# Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure

Tags: solidity

Remix has told me that the function state can be restricted to pure, however, I believe it can't. As you see, I am accessing external variables in return, can someone explain it to me?

```
function _getCreationFee(string memory merchantName) internal view returns (uint256) {
            uint8 nameLength = uint8(bytes(merchantName).length);
            if (nameLength == 3) {
                return baseMerchantFee * veryShortNameMultiplier;
            } else if (nameLength == 4) {
                return baseMerchantFee * shortNameMultiplier;
            } else {
                return baseMerchantFee;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are `baseMerchantFee`, `veryShortNameMultiplier` and  `shortNameMultiplier`? Are they constant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are accessing an external variable but not changing the value. **You should use Pure function state mutability.**You are only returning your input multiplied by the external variable. Your new code should appear as below;

```
function _getCreationFee(string memory merchantName) internal pure returns (uint256) {
            uint8 nameLength = uint8(bytes(merchantName).length);
            if (nameLength == 3) {
                return baseMerchantFee * veryShortNameMultiplier;
            } else if (nameLength == 4) {
                return baseMerchantFee * shortNameMultiplier;
            } else {
                return baseMerchantFee;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, It can't be pure. As you stated you are accessing external variables.
I went ahead and copy pasted this function to a contract in remix. It didn't give any warnings. And, gave an error and didn't compile when I declare it as Pure.

The problem might be about your compiler, try to reload and try with a newer compiler version.

Edit after comment: Constants can be reached within Pure functions. Because, to read constants you don't have to read from blockchain, it's written in the declaration and cannot be changed.

Comment: try adding this to the contract:
https://pastebin.com/WGq4V3VZ
(obviously not in the function haha)
let me know what happens

Comment: I assumed that your state variables can be changed by other functions but in your case they are constants. Constants can be reached within pure functions. You can make it pure.